# Train/Test split on specific ID /subject only

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to split my dataset into a train/test split. However instead of the regular percentage split, I want to make for example "subject01.dat" the test data and the other subjects the training data. How can I go about it?

If it matters, the dataset is a timeseries 3D data. But after my pre-processing, it turned into a 2D numpy array.

I was thinking of using `sklearn.test_train_split`,but what options can I set to ensure it keeps "subject01.dat" as the test dataset?

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dir = '/home/hanna/Documents/_DDA_Lab/Exercise6/PAMAP2_Dataset/Protocol/'
filelist = ['subject101.dat','subject102.dat','subject103.dat','subject104.dat','subject105.dat','subject106.dat','subject107.dat']

# Required columns
columns = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49]
# Required rows
ID_rows = [3,4,12,13]

for file in filelist:
    input = dir + file
    df = pd.read_csv(input, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    print('Done reading data file ', input)
    df = df[columns] # Keep only the required columns & drop the rest
    df = df[df[1].isin(ID_rows)] # Keep only the required rows & drop the rest
    df=df.fillna(0) # Replace NaNs with zeros
    df = (df - df.mean()) / df.std() # Normalize data
    data.append(df)


df = pd.concat(data) # Merge into one dataframe
print(df.shape)


# Convert dataframe into tensor
x_data = df.drop(1, axis=1).values
y_data = df[[1]].values


# Train / Test split
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.15, random_state=0)
```

Comment: That's not a train test split then, just keep `01.dat` manually and aggregate others to be train set. There's no point importing `train_test_split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understood correctly, but I think that you could just make a separate DataFrame for each file you want in your training set and a separate one for your test_set file(s).

For example, let's say subject101.dat will be your test set:

```py
filelist_test = ['subject101.dat']
filelist_train = ['subject102.dat','subject103.dat','subject104.dat','subject105.dat','subject106.dat','subject107.dat']

for train_file in filelist_train:
    # Do the same

train_df = pd.concat(data)

for test_file in filelist_test:
    # Do the same

test_df = pd.concat(data)
```

After that you could drop the label column you want and do the same as what you did before. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Also, I should scramble the test and training data. Any idea on it?

Comment: You could use ```train_test_split``` for that and just set percentage to 1. E.g. ```x, _ = train_test_split(x, test_size=1, random_state=80)```

Comment: ok thanks! i also found out about ```from sklearn.utils import shuffle
df = shuffle(df)```